# How to give port number MySql database in "Add Connection Window"

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, visual-studio-2010, database-connection

I have two versions of MySql in my database server. One of them is under 5.0 and the other one is 5.2. Older one looks 3306 port and the new one looks 3307 port. I want to use new one on my  .net project. When I try to give my server's IP address to Add Connection window, it looks 3306 port and says, "Connector/Net no longer supports server version prior to 5.0". I think it will be solved when I can give the port number.

[image]

Comment: Not answering the question, but you can probably add a connection string and this site is really helpful for that http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: @Kenny, I added a connection string but as you can see my other last question, I can not see that connection string in first step of this wizard.

Comment: did you try, servername:port, eg 192.168.1.4:3307?

Comment: @Jhon, yes I did and it says "Unable retrive the list of databases "

Comment: in Advanced parameters you can change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//connector-net-visual-studio-making-a-connection.html)

> You can also set the port to connect with the MySQL server by pressing
>   the Advanced button.

Answer (score 0):

Open Advanced settings by clicking "Advance" button and inside you'll find the port parameter and then change it, I've practiced it many times.

Answer (score 0):

After the ip just add ":portnumber" on the connection string